# How to execute multiple independent statements at the same time in Python/psycopg2?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have three materialized views in PostgreSQL that take very long time to refresh (more than a few hours each) and I need to refresh them every day.

I'm currently doing this using a Python script that refreshes the views one after the other but it takes thrice the amount of time compared to manually refreshing them in pgAdmin (where I can run all three refreshes simultaneously in different tabs).

This is how my code looks like right now:

```
import psycopg2
config = {'connection details'}
conn = psycopg2.connect(**config)
cur = conn.cursor()

# This is the part that I want to run simultaneously
cur.execute('REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW gsam.mv_hist_wip_data')
cur.execute('REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW gsam.mv_hist_ver_data')
cur.execute('REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW gsam.mv_hist_verda_data')

conn.close()
```

How can I execute three `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` statements at the same time  using Python and psycopg2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use multiprocessing pool please check the document [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). And check the below example

```
import psycopg2
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main():
    p = Pool(processes=3)
    view_names = ['mv_hist_wip_data','mv_hist_ver_data', 'mv_hist_verda_data']
    result = p.map(refresh_view, view_names)

def  refresh_view(view_name):

    config = {'connection details'}
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**config)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # This is the part that I want to run simultaneously
    cur.execute('REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW gsam.%s', (view_name,))
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works great! Only thing I had to change is the `def main():` as it was throwing an error. It should be `if __name__ == '__main__':`